# Sending arrays via ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I should send arrays via ajax jquery. How to do it using json? I tried:

```
    var type = [];
    var direction = [];
    var banks = [];

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#compareBtn").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'data.php',

              success: function(data){
                 alert(123);
              },
              data: JSON.stringify(type) + JSON.stringify(direction) + JSON+stringify(banks)
            });

        });
    });
```

And how should I get data from "data.php"?. Thank you

Comment: just send the array putting {} arround your array... the data parameter expects an object to be passed

Comment: "But it is not working" - you don't say? Surely you wouldn't have asked if it worked. "Not working" is **not at all useful** for someone trying to help you. State your problem clearly and **precisely.**

Comment: Use it like this data: {data:data,direction:direction,banks:banks}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass all of the arrays using object notation and let jQuery automatically encode it.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'data.php',
  dataType : 'json', 
  contentType : "application/json",               
  success: function(data){
     alert(123);
  },
  data: {
      type : type,
      direction : direction,
      banks : banks
  }
});
```

then in data.php you can do something like this

```
$type = json_decode($_POST["type"]); //to get the data
... //work with the data
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: data.php doesn't work, do you have any assumptions why? p.s.Everything works perfect if write only echo "1", for example, so mistake is there

Comment: "doesn't work" is too broad...what doesnt work exactly? maybe you should ask a new question and link it here

Comment: There is no alert(123) calling

Comment: if you press F12 in most browsers (IE, Chrome) it will reveal developer tools...using that you can see your network errors, one that is caused by your failed php...but like i said this seems like a new question that you should ask in a new thread